# Encrypt Data in Firebase Side rather than in Android Code

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Instead of encrypting data and storing in firebase and decrypting the data is there a way where we can save encrypt data at firebase without altering android code.

Comment: You Can Use Firebase Function To Change new or Exist Data
when Some Action is happened 

Like backend Server

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Realtime Database runs on top of Google Cloud Platform, so the data stored is already encrypted on the disk level.

The Firebase Realtime Database client and server communicate over HTTPS, so the data is already encrypted in transit.

You could set up a Cloud Function or other endpoint to do an additional layer of encryption. Just keep in mind that there too, the communication between the clients and that server will go (at best) over HTTPS.

If you want additional end-to-end encryption on top of that, you'll have to do this in your application code. That's pretty much the definition of end-to-end encryption. :)